# Menu designed for use without mouse. What is the best way to implement?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, embedded-linux

I'm writing a GUI using QT for embedded system with linux. This device has no mouse. Only display and specific keyboard with keys: up, down, return and 7 number keys.

The software will be used to set some parameters of device and read them (some charts also).

#### Example of how menu could look:

[image: Untitled.png]

after `OPTION 1` selected

[image: Untitled2.png]

After `SUBOPTION 1` selected some table with data is loaded.

Sometimes after selecting option i need to load specific widget and sometimes just another set of options.

1. I think it is possible to implement custom labels and kind of list widget that aligns them.
2. I guess it is also possible to use Qt's MVC classes for it. They are highly customizable, but i never made custom views and delegates.
3. Maybe i just need to create QtListView with stringlist model and apply stylesheet to it so it gets look more like buttons. And based on selection in list load next widget.

Which way is better and why?
Is there any easier ways to accomplish this?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems rather opinion-based to me, but I think option 3 is the easiest and would be sufficient.

Comment: The problem statement is broad enough that there are multiple reasonable ways to accomplish what you want, and it's not really feasible to determine which is "better".

Comment: Why a `QListView`? To align `QLabel`s or `QPushButton`s or whatever, I would use a `QVBoxLayout` or `QGridLayout`. The list widget might provide selection and ready navigation of up and down but together with a lot of other features you probably don't need nor want. Btw. `QLabel` is derived from `QFrame`. To achieve some kind of button style is quite simple.

Comment: Concerning Qt's MVC, I must admit I'm not that enthusiastic. It caused us a lot of head-ache to get this stable and the performance we need (e.g. for trees with huge number of nodes which change from time to time). (May be, I'm a little too spoiled by the gtkmm I used before.)